# Is it possible to intercept private methods using unity 3.0?

Tags: unity-container, private, interception

I want to inject some aspects in to methods/properties regardless whether it is private, public or protected.

I have gone through many blogs and forums and couldn't find a helpful article on this.

Can any one guide me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations on how Unity intercept certain methods. Certainly it is a value-added feature on top of standard DI facilities provided by the framework. As far as I know, non of the Unity versions do not support AOP style interception on private methods, and constructors. [TransparentProxyInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940631/unity-interceptors-transparentproxyinterceptor) would only intercept only the type's implemented interfaces or the type used by [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) And the [VirtualMethodInterceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.interceptionextension.virtualmethodinterceptor.aspx) would only intecept on virtual methods.

I don't think any new interceptors have been added to the [Interception in v3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178467%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx).
Also note that usual private/protected even internal methods require special intervention for AOP style interception. This is more less out of bound for Unity because it requires IL re-writing which usually handled by dedicated AOP framworks such as [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/).